# R: error in mget - invalid first argument

Tags: r, debugging

```
library(RMallow)
dummy = data.frame(item1 = c(1.5, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2),
                   item2 = c(1.5, 3, 1.5, 2, 2, 3),
                   item3 = c(3, 1, 1.5, 3, 3, 1))
mallows(dummy, G = 1, iter = 10)
```

I'm playing around with the `mallows` function, but I get the following error: `Error in mget(plabels[hasSubclass], env) : invalid first argument`. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: I don't use this library, but `?mget` says that its first argument, x, is a character vector of object names. I would double check that you are feeding `mallows` the correct obejct classes in your arguments.

Comment: @lmo Hm...the thing is that I've ran the code on my old computer successfully many times. After switching to a new laptop, it doesn't really run anymore. So I'm pretty sure I'm feeding the function the right parameters, but I'm wondering if something else could be causing this problem?

Comment: I downloaded the packaged and tried to run your example. The function is called `Mallows` now with a capital `M` now and it also throws an error that the `object i not found` if I run it the way you do. Perhaps you need an update?